# onReceive being called infinite times

Tags: android, service, broadcast

In my service I have,

```
Log.e("ActivateHome","VibrateMeeting");
            Intent i = new Intent(this, VibrateMeetingsReceiver.class);
            meetingPi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 000010, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            meetingAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            meetingAlarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, meetingPi);
```

My Broadcast Receiver,

```
Log.e("VibrateMeetingReceiver","Reached");
             Intent newIntent = new Intent(context,VibrateMeetingsService.class);
             context.startService(newIntent);
```

Whats happening is that the broadcastReceiver is being called a million times which Force Closes my app. I know this because the Log.e in my broadcase receiver is being printed infinite times. Also, in my VibrateMeetingsService, the onStartCommand is being called as many times as the broadCast Receiver.

Whats causing this problem? Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: You are starting a repeating alarm, that starts a broadcast receiver that starts the service .. that sets a repeating alarm again. And you are passing in `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the first time to trigger the alarm - i.e. it will trigger *immediately* and schedule a new alarm etc. etc.. (Oh, and INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES is intended to be used with `setInexactRepeating`, although it should work since it's *currently* defined as 900000 ms).

Comment: I understand that it triggers immediately. However, why would it keep calling multiple times? Shouldnt it just call the onReceive once? It is calling immediately so many times that my app crashes!

Comment: Where are you calling `meetingAlarm.setRepeating` in your `Service`?

Comment: the method is called vibrateMeetings() and it is only being called once. I can confirm so because the "Log.e("ActivateHome","VibrateMeeting");" statement is only executed once!